# WebRTC NodeJS Server Architecture

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I'm interested in building a web application similar to TinyChat where multiple users can be in a room and broadcast their audio/video feeds to everyone else in the room. I've been looking at WebRTC and it looks pretty easy to get started with a P2P setup, but I'm having trouble finding out how to do WebRTC with a client/server architecure.

I've watched [Google's presentation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2HzZkd2A40) on WebRTC and the different network topologies common in working with WebRTC. The one I'm most interested in is that in working with an MCU where the MCU is responsible for broadcasting the data to everyone else in the room, thus eliminating P2P.

My question is, how would I go about this? Are there any working examples? Prefferably, I'd like to work with NodeJS on the server-side but haven't found any libraries for handling it. The only two things I have found are [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/) and [Licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/), but they both appear to be more than I'm interested in at this point in time. I'm basically just wanting something that takes the WebRTC connection and then broadcasts it out to the appropriate users in the same room. I'm not worried about transcoding, muxing, or recording right now.

Comment: What you're talking about is taking a potentially massive data stream (or several in parallel) and duplicating and retransmitting them to other peers in as close to realtime as possible. **This is not a task Javascript will be very good at.** No libraries exist because it's close to impossible to make Javascript do this. You *are* looking for a more involved solution such as Kurento.